# How to calculate the probability of observing an event given by the multinomial tail probability

Tags: p-value, multinomial-distribution

I have seen in the article of Lossos et al.(Blood. 2000 Mar 1;95(5):1797-803.) this formula

[image]

Could you please explain me what the 0.5 represent in the P-value of an observed r1 ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It has to do with the definition of p-value is that it is the probability of observing as extreme or more extreme a value as the observed under the null hypothesis.  So determine what the multinomial distribution would be under the null hypothesis.